# Get records unique on both fields in a many-to-many relation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get all one to one relations in a many to many table.

In the example below the only record I want to return would be the last (3,3)

```
PaymentID InvoiceID
1          1
1          2
2          2
3          3
```

The closest I have gotten is

```
Select * from Table where PaymentID in (
select PaymentID from Table t
inner join (
    select InvoiceId from Table 
    group by InvoiceId
    having count(InvoiceId) = 1
) inv on t.InvoiceId = inv.InvoiceId
group by PaymentId
having count(PaymentId) = 1
)
```

This will return 1 and 3

Any Ideas greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY paymentId) AS pcnt,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY invoiceId) AS icnt
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   pcnt = 1
        AND icnt = 1
```